# Django: Retrieving the number of objects after applying distinct() method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a course model which looks like:

```
class Course(models.Model):
         
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    course_university = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100) # lastname
    course_instructor_fn = models.CharField(max_length=100) # firstname
    """
    More fields are here
    """
```

Now I have selected instructors for each university using:

```
 qs = Course.objects.filter(course_university__iexact=uni).order_by('course_instructor','course_instructor_fn','course_university').distinct('course_instructor','course_instructor_fn','course_university')
```

My intention is to now count each the distinct `course_code` for each instructor using an aggregate `Count()` function:

so I am trying to basically do:

`new_qs = Course.objects.filter(id__in=qs).annotate(course_count=Count('course_code', distinct=True).values_list('course_instructor_fn', 'course_instructor', 'course_count')`

However, currently, I only get **1** for `user_count` no matter how many courses each instructor has.

My intention is to get the number of courses each instructor offers. How can I do this successfully?

Comment: It is normally better to make an `Instructor` model and then use a `ForeignKey` from `Course` to `Instructor`. This will make querying also a lot easier.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without setting up a new model? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: please don't. The current modeling results in more disk usage, slower queries, data duplication, a lot of potential problems to keep data in sync, etc.

Comment: a simple example. What if you later discover that there is a typo in the instructor's first name. Then you will need to run a quite expensive query to update all the `Course` records. But more troublesome is if you also have such `CharField`s on other models, then it will result in a *lot* of queries to update the first name everywhere. To make matters worse, if you add an extra model with an instructor, you will have to look at *all* views that somehow create/edit/update an instructor to see how you can fix this. It thus also eventually results in a lot of implementation work.